# Delete filename from a filepath in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to remove the filename of a path e.g.:

```
/vmfs/volumes/50153b66-6aac5486-e942-080027a10080/TestMachine/TestMachine.vmx
```

Would result in:

```
/vmfs/volumes/50153b66-6aac5486-e942-080027a10080/TestMachine/
```

Bearing in mind that the file name might change, would a regex be the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Path.GetDirectoryName will /'s to \'s.

```
var filepath = "/vmfs/volumes/50153b66-6aac5486-e942-080027a10080/TestMachine/TestMachine.vmx";
var directorypath = filepath.Substring(0, filepath.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
// /vmfs/volumes/50153b66-6aac5486-e942-080027a10080/TestMachine/
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath);
// \vmfs\volumes\50153b66-6aac5486-e942-080027a10080\TestMachine
```

Comment: Accepted, because you are bang on, with the trails, since its a linux path, the "/" are turned to "\"

Answer (score 6):

You may use:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
Path.GetDirectoryName()
```

more info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is a method in System.IO.Path for that

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("/vmfs/volumes/50153b66-6aac5486-e942-080027a10080/TestMachine/TestMachine.vmx")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly heavy approach, but sometimes it's nice to know you're using a bulletproof technique...

```
var path = new UriBuilder("file", "/vmfs/volumes/50153b66-6aac5486-e942-080027a10080/TestMachine/TestMachine.vmx");
var parent = new Uri(path.Uri, "..");

 Console.WriteLine(parent.AbsolutePath);
```

Result:

```
 /vmfs/volumes/50153b66-6aac5486-e942-080027a10080/TestMachine/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strPath = "/vmfs/volumes/50153b66-6aac5486-e942-080027a10080/TestMachine/TestMachine.vmx";

string[] strFileParts = strPath.Split( '\\' );
if ( strFileParts.Length > 0 )
{
    str =  strFileParts[strFileParts.Length - 1] );
}

result = full_path - str;
```